# Create folder and move files from one drive to another

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive

I am totally new to ubuntu and I had installed ubuntu on a 8GB virtual disk using Virtualbox.Then I added another virtual drive to ubuntu (Ubuntu Disk 2) of 4 gb as follows

[image]
Then I formatted the new disk as ext4 as a primary partiton using Gparted partiton editor.

[image]

However I am unable to create a new folder or move files to this new disk.How can I create a folder or move data to this new hard drive.I would also like to whether I can install software under this new Drive(4gb) instead of the old (8gb) drive.

Comment: It looks OK to me, can you show us the permissions tab, or maybe you see some error message. I mean, you are not supposed to do anything more than what you've done, it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to boot into Ubuntu on the VM your issue is likely with your vdi setup. If you're new to VirtualBox this can be tricky, not to mention if you're new to Linux. You should take a look at this for how to set up the new vdi and partition/format/mount it in Linux:

http://www.vitalsofttech.com/add-disk-storage-to-oracle-virtualbox-with-linux/

If you're more a fan of graphical utilities you might want to look into the use of gparted for partitioning and formatting the disks inside Ubuntu:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/